# webdriver - Get a count on all class names contained within a specific div

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using webdriver with c#, I'm trying to get a count of all items contained within a specific drop down menu (it's not a select element).  The trouble is, there are many other elements on my page containing the same class name so what I need is a way to filter class names within a specific div only.

Here is an example of the code I'm looking at:

```
<div id="DropDownMenu1">
<span class="drop-combobox">
<div class="drop-item-content">list item number 1</div></div>
<div class="drop-item-content">list item number 2</div></div>
<div class="drop-item-content">list item number 3</div></div>
</span>
</div>
```

Throughout my page I will also have additional drop down menus like this (all class names are the same - just the div's have a different name):

```
  <div id="DropDownMenu2">
    <span class="drop-combobox">
    <div class="drop-item-content">list item number 1</div></div>
    <div class="drop-item-content">list item number 2</div></div>
    <div class="drop-item-content">list item number 3</div></div>
    </span>
    </div>

 <div id="DropDownMenu3">
    <span class="drop-combobox">
    <div class="drop-item-content">list item number 1</div></div>
    <div class="drop-item-content">list item number 2</div></div>
    <div class="drop-item-content">list item number 3</div></div>
    </span>
    </div>
```

I have been able to get a count using (from memory) something like this:

```
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("drop-item-content").Count());
```

Trouble is, my count returns all classes with the name of "drop-item-content" but I need to get a count on all class names contained within 1 specific div.

I hope that makes sense (and I hope that someone could help)  :)

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using XPath to find all elements,

```
//div[@id='DropDownMenu1']//div[@class='drop-item-content']
```

FindElements will hold all the classes inside the specified div,

```
driver.FindElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='DropDownMenu1']//div[@class='drop-item-content']").Count());
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping - This answer worked best for me.   p.s I have been away hence the delay in getting back ;)

Answer (score 3):

You try to get first, the hole element with the id, then you filter with the element(div in thi case becasue the span you do not want it) and then, use the class name.The class name is not requred becasue you want all the Div, in case the selector fail, use it with out the class name. CssSelector must work. Try the next line:

```
Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#DropDownMenu3 div.drop-item-content").count();
```

Answer (score 2):

From top of my head:

```
WebElement masterDiv = driver.FindElements(By.Id("DropDownMenu3"));
// Find subelements of that element
int count = masterDiv.FindElements(By.XPath("./div[@class="drop-item-content"])).Count();
```

Comment: @OP: Alternatively: `By.CssSelector("div.drop-item-content")` if you want to simplify things, but Erki has this right.  This is what you want.

Comment: @sircapsalot You have suggested css selector as an alternative and also xpath too can do it. So, is there any specific advantage in finding elements the way erki suggested?

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam There are little advantages that XPath has over CSS selectors, but in my years of experience with selenium, i've been just fine using PURE CSS.. It's cleaner, and just easier to use.  An advantage that xpath has over CSS, is it's `..` selector.  in CSS, you can't go UP to the parents. you can only select.. however i've never had a problem finding an element using CSS. However the main advantage of using CSS, is that it's easier to read.  Compare:  `//div[contains(@class, 'hello')]` compared to: `div.hello`

Comment: @sircapsalot ya thats true, but i was comparing my answer with erki's, where he is finding the `master div` and then the `sub div`  instead of a simple `xpath` or `css path` wondering which approach might be good in any context.

Comment: Yea, you can definitely simplify what I wrote, but I wanted to demonstrate how to find subelements of an element by using `./` (not the entire markup), it comes very handy when your markup gets really complex and lacks of identifiers. But yeah, I could have been more verbose here.